# "Application executable is missing a required architecture armv6" on Application loader

Tags: loader, layer, armv7, armv6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [application executable is missing a required architecture armv6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053466/application-executable-is-missing-a-required-architecture-armv6)

When i run my layarapplication on my device it works, but when i want to upload it with application loader to appstore, it gives a message; 
"***application executable is missing a required architecture At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv*6**"

I've set the "**Build active architect Only**" to "**NO**", the message dissapears but another problem will occurs what i can't fix..

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/liblayarplayer.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv6)

"*_OBJC_CLASS_$_LPAugmentedRealityViewController", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in LayarViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status*"

Anyone id?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with application loader may be solved adding to your info.plist file:

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>armv7</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

_OBJC_CLASS_$_LPAugmentedRealityViewController requires armv7.