# application executable is missing a required architecture armv6

Tags: ios

I am using xCode 4.2 and trying to deploy my application. I am failing the validation with the following error message:

```
application executable is missing a required architecture armv6
```

The value for my Architectures is set to Standard (armv7). This is the ONLY option in the dropdownlist. 
Base SDK: iOS 5.0 (This is the only option) 
Deployment SDK: 3.2 
Build Active Architecture Only: NO 
Valid Architectures: armv6 armv7 armv7f armv7k

Does anyone please know the solution to this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable is missing a required architecture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393701/iphone-ipod-touch-application-executable-is-missing-a-required-architecture)

Comment: Actually the duplicate question has a different solution which is to revert back to the old version of xCode. I was wondering if there is some way to solve this problem for the current version.

Comment: Turns out the only solution is to uninstall xCode 4.2 and install xCode 4.1

Comment: As iOS 5.0 and Xcode 4.2 are beta software, they are still under NDA.  Your best bet is to discuss them at Apple's Developer Forums: http://devforums.apple.com .  If you encounter a bug with the tools, be sure to file a report at https://bugreport.apple.com .

Answer (score 83):

In the Xcode 4.2 GM this is still a problem but you can resolve it by doing the following.

1. Switch to the files/folders view in xcode project
2. Select your Project ( the blue icon)
3. Select your Application under Targets in the middle of the screen.
4. Go To build settings
5. Find Architectures > Distribution
6. Expand this section so you can see both Debug and Release
7. Change "Standard (armv7) - $(ARCH_STANDARD_32_BIT)" to "Other..."
8. Replace, "Standard (armv7) - $(ARCH_STANDARD_32_BIT)" with "armv6", then add a new item "armv7"

Remember you may need to do this for all included projects aka frameworks such as TAPKU

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand the step 8... Could you elaborate please?

Comment: If you select OTHER from the drop down, you get a box that had grids, you can add armv6 on one line and armv7 on the next line. The screen shot you added is wrong.

Comment: Make sure "Build Active Architecture Only" is Set to "No" Otherwise if you are connected to device it will build for that device only...

Answer (score 46):

For Xcode 4.5, set the deployment target to at least iOS 4.3 and that will resolve it. armv6 and earlier versions of iOS are almost extinct.

Comment: Thanks very much for this, it has cost me a 2-hour headache already!

Comment: yeah, setting the target to iOS 4.3 solves the issue in the latest 4.5.1 too... thx

Answer (score 40):

Easy way to do it:

1) Left-click project icon (**blue icon**, under "Run" button).

2) Next to the project icon (to the right of it), left-click on **project name** under **"PROJECT"** (White background).

3) Select tab **"Build Settings"** and look for submenu **"Architectures"** (First one). Left-click on **"Standard (armv7) $(ARCH_STANDARD_32_BIT)"** and select **"Other..."**

4) Click on the **"-"** icon to remove original value (**"$(ARCH_STANDARD_32_BIT)"**). Click the **"+"** icon and write **"armv6"** (without double-quotes). Click the **"+"** icon again and add **"armv7"** (also without double-quotes). Click **"Done"**.

5) Make sure that **"Build Active Architecture Only"** is set to **"No"** (it should be)

6) Next to the project icon (to the right of it), left-click on **project name** under **"TARGETS"** and repeat steps 3, 4 and 5.

7) Press **cmd + I** on your keyboard (or **Product -> Profile** on Xcode menu) and check to see if everything is ok.

Comment: I find these instructions to be more clear, but don't forget this important note from @J3RM: "Remember you may need to do this for all included projects aka frameworks such as TAPKU"

Comment: my settings were such that "Build Active Architecture Only" was set to true -- thanks for the solution!

Comment: In step 4 you mentioned click Done. But I do not see any DOne button. :/ Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5):

My environment was Xcode 4.5.1. Changing two things solved this issue for me.

1. Setting the deployment target to at least iOS 4.3.
2. Keeping only armv7 architecture in the Architectures list under build settings and removing all others (including armv6) explicitly.

Comment: Yup, me too.  My iPad-only app refused to build, until I removed armv7s from the list of architectures.

Answer (score 4):

I stumble upon this question when looking for a solution to the warning:

```
warning: iPad: application executable is missing a required architecture.
At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv7 (-19033)
Unable to validate your application. - (null)
```

Other answers did not solve my problem, then I realized I changed a value of `CFBundleExecutable`. When I returned to the old value everything went smoothly again.

I'm not sure what is a direct cause of that warning but at least I can distribute Ad Hoc builds again.

Comment: Really weird, got the same warning and along with some unrelated ones. Changed the value of `CFBundleExecutable` back to what it was and all went fine. Thank!

Answer (score 3):

All of the answers didn't help for my case, using Xcode 4.2.1.

What I did was changing `Architectures` from `armv7` to `armv6 armv7` and it worked. Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Adding armv6 was only partially the problem for me to resolve the same issue with Xcode 4.5. I also had to increase my deployment target from iOS 4.1 to iOS 5.0 to get it to work. Many hours of frustration for such a simply fix. Hope it helps.

Comment: Increasing the target to 4.3 suffices.

Answer (score -1):

For me it helped when I set only `armv6` under Architectures