# Unable to validate application for iOS App Store, armv6 architecture missing

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, armv6, deployment-target

While submitting my iOS App to the App Store, validation fails with the message:

```
iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable is missing a required architecture.
At least one of the following architectures(s) must be present: armv6
```

I'm using Xcode 4.5 (4G182), currently the latest. Some of my build settings:

- Architectures: armv6 armv7
- Base SDK: Latest iOS (iOS 6.0)
- Valid Architectures: armv7 armv7s
- iOS Deployment Target: 4.0

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Set the **iOS Deployment Target** to **iOS 4.3**.

Comment: XCode 4.5 can't build for lower than 4.3, which have no devices that uses armv6. As suggested above, use 4.3 as deployment target, and additionally, include armv7s (use the STANDARD option and it will be included) to optimize your code for the iPhone 5.

Comment: Thank you... This solved the problem for me. Not very happy about Apple's useless validation error messages, their decision to drop armv6 in XCode 4.5, and me wasting well over an hour late at night trying to figure it out!

Comment: @Clafou : Completely agree. I followed [this answer] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053466/application-executable-is-missing-a-required-architecture-armv6) exactly and hence error kept appearing. Wasted my one hour too.. Then I saw this answer and figured out the way.. Damn!!

Comment: Exact same situation I was in except I didn't set armv6 Architecture only armv7 but iOS Deployment Target was 4.0 when I changed to 4.3 I got it working.. and yes I was using XCode 4.5 as well. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Xcode 4.5 there is no armv6 any longer
Then you need to use an earlier Xcode version to still support iOS 4.3
(various ways doing this are listed here http://blog.chpwn.com/post/31824877081)

If this is not necessary you could cut out armv6 and just support iOS 5+

Cutting out armv6 goes by -> `Build Settings->Architectures->Select Standard`