# iPhone Validation Issue Armv6 then non public api

Tags: iphone, ios, validation

So I am having some troubles right now with validating my iPhone app.  I have made 3 apps before and have never experienced this.  First when I attempt to validate xcode tells me that it needs the architecture armv6 so I add it then it tells me I am using a non-public api and some other stuff.  I have added some screen shots below of exactly what is said.  Thanks so much for you help it advance I really really appreciate it[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The validation error is quite specific: uniqueIdentifer is a deprecated method from the UIDevice class, as of iOS 5.0. Search for an instance of `[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]` in your code and use any number of replacements that Apple suggests (e.g. from the NSUUID class).

Comment: As for the required architecture, please see this link: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053466/application-executable-is-missing-a-required-architecture-armv6].